# Is it possible to check a date in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a Microsoft SQL Server stored procedure which takes an `account ID`, and returns an authentication ticket and whether the ticket is expired.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Authentication.ticket, Authentication.TicketExpires < getDate()
FROM Authentication WHERE Authentication.accountID = @id
```

The purpose is to return a row with two columns - the ticket, and a bit field (0 or 1) telling me whether the ticket is expired. This bit field isn't part of the table, the `ticketExpires` column is `SMALLDATETIME`.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "return a BIT" field - Your query (assuming it's syntactically correct) should be generating a boolean value (True or False) for that date comparison.  What is the SQL server returning? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 3):

I think this achieves what you're looking for. Hope this helps.

```
 SELECT
      Authentication.Ticket
      , CAST(CASE
           WHEN Authentication.TicketExpires < GetDate() THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END AS bit) AS 'IsExpired'
 FROM Authentication
 WHERE Authentication.accountID = @id
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the information on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) any use?

It looks like you'll have to write something like the following:

```
select  cast(datediff(s,Authentication.TicketExpires,getdate()) as bit) from ...
```

This will return a 1 if the ticket expiry date is in the future, and a 0 if it is exactly now or in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Most database systems have built in functions for things like this.  In MySQL, you would use `NOW()` for example.  A quick Google for "Date and time functions MS SQL Server" got me to a page that says the function `GETDATE()` will return a `DATETIME` of the current system timestamp.  I'm not sure if you can compare a `SMALLDATETIME` to a `DATETIME`, though.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I've found the date functions, but I don't know how to return a BIT field which is generated as part of the query.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question.  That's a bit more complicated, and beyond my SQL ability. :-)